# Adding Code Samples to A Slideshow Presentation

Tags: ruby

I'm making my first technical presentation, and I'd like to add some code samples (ruby in my case).  What's the smart way to have nicely formatted with color code samples?

For example, when I code VIM looks like the attached image.  I'd like to duplicate something similar in my presentation without manually changing the colors of characters.
[image]

Comment: On OS-X, X-Code can create code previews.  Not sure if it works with ruby though.

Answer (score 1):

MagicPoint can easily [include images into slides](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/mgp/SYNTAX), so if you've got screenshots of your code (as you do here), you can simply:

```
%image "index.png"
```

inside your slide's content.

If you're looking to avoid taking manual screenshots, you can probably convince [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) or [coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) to emit output in some format that can be used with MagicPoint's `%filter` command.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do that, I used PDF-Latex with the class "beamer" for the presentation and the package "[listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/)" for code samples. It supports syntax highlighting including colors for Ruby.

After some initial learning, it worked like a charm.